# google metric calculator?

Tags: .net, metrics

I want to make some conversions in my app to convert, let's say feet to km, gallons to liters, etc. I really like how does google handle this kind of conversion requests.
do they have any API to use it?
I've found examples on how to convert currencies with google using google's undocumented API.
I'm not looking for the currency conversion rate, I want to have just a basic metric <-> imperial conversion, based on the input

any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: This only does currency, but perhaps it will help in your search: http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/

Comment: thanks, will continue to research if it is possible.